# get xml data from remote server in php

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I want get xml data from remote server using php.This is my code to get xml but i got bool(false)

```
<?php 
   header ("content-type: text/plain");
   $filename = file_get_contents("http://gep4.com/radio/wp-content/plugins/haze_radio/readme.txt");
   var_dump($filename);
?>
```

Comment: true CURL. maybe remote server need header info...

Answer (score 0):

That means there was error getting the content of the file. Have you made sure the file exists or you have permission to read the file or something else?

> [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
>
> Return Values
>
> The function returns the read data or FALSE on failure

Comment: file is on another server but is there is any another way to get xml data in php or jquery plz help me

Comment: this is the simplest way to get file contents in PHP and I think you need to solve the issue first. Type the file in the browser, can you access it? Other methods are `fopen`, `curl`. Look at the other answers

Answer (score 0):

Probably [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) is disabled in php.ini

Either enable it, if you have access ot php.ini

Or, try [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead

Sample CURL call

```
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    // set url 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com"); 

    //return the transfer as a string 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    // $output contains the output string 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 

    // close curl resource to free up system resources 
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get data it is working

```
function getPage($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.8');

$result['EXE'] = curl_exec($ch);
$result['INF'] = curl_getinfo($ch);
$result['ERR'] = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);
 unset($url, $referer, $agent, $header, $timeout);
return $result;
}
$url = "http://gep4.com/radio/wp-content/plugins/haze_radio/readme.txt";
var_dump(getPage($url) );
```